# (Very Basic) If user types then write

Tags: pascal

**Variable observe : String;**

read(observe);

If observe

then write('You are in a cave etc');

**---------------------------**

All I want to do is if the user types observe then the program writes something.

Above is my logic, and the compiler says a Boolean is expected.
I tried google but the IF tutorials only showed if(A = 5) then etc.

Comment: `if observe = 'observe' then ...` presumably, but I don't know what exactly `read` does in Pascal.

Comment: From what I learned its supposed to read what the user types.

Comment: Oh hey if **observe = 'observe' then** worked, thanks :d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` requires a boolean expression.  You have given it a string.

Probably you want to compare the string to something:

```
if observe = 'observe'
  then do_something
```